# Current Function only declares once and need to declare multiple

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

[-SUBJECT SITE-](http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/product-category/shop/cooking-appliances/)

In my Wordpress woocommerce site, the function im currently using only works with one unique video on one unique category page. This function only declares once. I want to manipulate it so i can call out different category pages and have unique videos on each page.

Working function for a video on ONE page:

```
<?php function woo_add_video_on_category_page() {

if ( is_product_category( 'cooking-appliances' ) ) {
    echo '<iframe width="990" height="500" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/rxX9PRhvIL0?list=PL959AE597E59B6863" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woo_add_video_on_category_page' );

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the $url parameter and pass as needed.

```
<?php function woo_add_video_on_category_page($url) {

if ( is_product_category( 'cooking-appliances' ) ) {
    echo '<iframe width="990" height="500" src="$url" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>    </iframe>';
}}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woo_add_video_on_category_page' );

?>
```